# string concatenation from a .txt file matlab

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation, strcat

I am trying to concatenate three lines (I want to leave the lines as is; 3 rows) from Shakespeare.txt file that shows:

```
To be,
or not to be:
that is the question.
```

My code right now is

```
fid = fopen('Shakespeare.txt')
while ~feof(fid)
a = fgets(fid);
b = fgets(fid);
c = fgets(fid);
end
fprintf('%s', strcat(a, b, c))
```

I'm supposed to use strcat and again, I want concatenated and leave them as three rows.

Comment: You can put in the form of a string array is that what you want?

Comment: You already have the three lines in three separate variables. What result do you want exactly? A cell array of these lines? A string array?

Answer (score 1):

One method of keeping the rows separate is by storing the lines of the text file in a string array. Here a 1 by 3 string array is used. It may also be a good idea to use `fgetl()` which grabs each line of the text file at a time. Concantenating the outputs of `fgetl()` as strings may also be another option to ensure the they do not get stored as character (char) arrays. Also using the `\n` indicates to line break when printing the strings within the array `String_Array`.

```
fid = fopen('Shakespeare.txt');
while ~feof(fid)
    
String_Array(1) = string(fgetl(fid));
String_Array(2) = string(fgetl(fid));
String_Array(3) = string(fgetl(fid));
end

fprintf('%s\n', String_Array);
```

[image: Output result:]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**